# Android HttpurlConnection read data using BufferedReader but get null value after append it to a StringBuilder

Tags: android, post, httpurlconnection, bufferedreader, stringbuilder

I got data from `reader.readLine()`. But it doesn't enter the while loop. The return 'json' string is null.

Someone please help me to solve the issue. i have already tried a lot for a correct solution.

```
try {            
    URL urL = new URL(url);
    urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urL.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    urlConnection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(15000);
    urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
            .appendQueryParameter("PackageName", packagename);

    String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

    OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
            new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(query);
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    os.close();

    urlConnection.connect();

    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

    Log.e("READER","....."+reader.readLine());
    String line=reader.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        result.append(line).append('\n');
    }
    json=result.toString();
    in.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
}
Log.e("RESULT","...."+json);
return json;
```

Comment: I think your code includes `try {` ___ look just above the code snippet you shared ___

Comment: No the try block is closed before catch statement

Comment: Atlast I got it. The issue was on the line  Log.e("READER","....."+reader.readLine());
    String line=reader.readLine();  
I changed the above lines as 
 String line=reader.readLine(); 
Log.e("READER","....."+line);
Now its working fine...
Thank you all for the support..:)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra `reader.readLine()` in the log,

```
Log.e("READER","....." + reader.readLine());
```

Try this code,

```
Log.e("ResponseCode", "" + urlConnection.getResponseCode());

InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
json = result.toString();
in.close();
```

Comment: Thank You for the suggestion. I have already do the same. But still the same problem. :(

Comment: Make sure you are getting data from the API. Try it in the browser.

Comment: Yes, the data is getting from API

Comment: it does'nt enter the while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) loop

Answer (score 0):

Do this it's basic maybe you missed it :

```
   json=result.toString();
    in.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    urlConnection.disconnect();
}
Log.e("RESULT","...."+json);
if (json!=null)
return json;
```

It will skip null pointer exception:

Comment: No, it's not solving my issue

Answer (score 0):

If all you are doing is downloading a jsonString from the API, this should sort you out:

```
String jsonString = "";

    try {

        URL mURL = new URL(yourURL);

        HttpURLConnection mHttpURLConnection;
        mHttpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)mURL.openConnection();

        mHttpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);

        mHttpURLConnection.connect();

        InputStream mInputStream = mHttpURLConnection.getInputStream();

        int i = 0;
        while ((i = mInputStream.read()) != -1) {
            jsonString += (char) i;
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
Log.e("JSON","Json String received: " + jsonString);
```